# sql - update several rows based on a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update several rows from data of a specific row
THIS IS A SINGLE TABLE, `ItemNum` is unique
my attempt:

```
UPDATE myTable t, (SELECT DISTINCT width, repeat
            FROM myTable
            WHERE ItemNum='80644') t1
SET t.width = t1.width
AND SET t.repeat = t1.repeat
WHERE ItemNum='80645'
AND WHERE ItemNum='80646'
```

gives me an error
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM myTable WHERE ItemNum='80644') t1 SET t.width' at line 2`

when i run this for a single row it works
but the syntax for multiple rows seem to be the issue

```
UPDATE myTable t, (SELECT DISTINCT width
  FROM myTable
  WHERE ItemNum='80644') t1
SET t.width = t1.width
WHERE ItemNum='80645'
```

Comment: There are quite a few issues with this. Have you looked up the proper syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

    UPDATE table SET t.width=t1.width, t.repeat=t1.repeat WHERE t.ItemNum=# AND t.ItemNum=#;

Comment: Also how are you joining your tables? Can you show some of your mysql schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work, but it won't give reliable results if there are more than one rows with itemnum=80644

```
UPDATE myTable t
join
    (SELECT DISTINCT width, repeat
            FROM myTable
            WHERE ItemNum='80644') t1
    on t.ItemNum in ('80645','80646')
SET
    t.width = t1.width,
    t.repeat = t1.repeat
```

Comment: Right. He needs a join clause here.

Comment: Sorry, added join. been a little bit since MySQL. hope that works

Comment: still getting an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from myTable t join (SELECT DISTINCT width, repeat FROM ' at line 5  `

Comment: @Phil I think he wont be able to do this update. From t-q's response above on the main question, he's trying to do a join on the same table he's updating. Mysql doesn't allow this.

Comment: OK, thanks Shawn.  I was unaware of that restriction.

Comment: Here is some additional documentation. You have to use a subquery as a temp table... http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,265513,265891

Comment: Michael updated the code again t q.  Not sure if that will work for you but the page Shawn linked has an explanation

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.width = t1.width
AND SET t.repeat = t1.repeat
FROM  myTable t INNER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT width, repeat
            FROM myTable
            WHERE ItemNum='80644') t1
ON ItemNum in ('80645'
```

,'80646')

update statement can have only one table name 
the table it has to update

supporting tables can be specified in join to facilitate the update statement

Comment: I dont think this is proper mysql syntax.